# iOS Application Development : Beginner

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I'm looking for some help with the following. This will be a very general and vague question but i would appreciate people's input.

I'm currently learning Objective-C with the idea of developing applications for iOS. So far it is going ok - i'm obviously starting at the bottom, "Hello World", adding two numbers etc. Next i'm going to be making my own calculator.

Other technologies i'm familiar with are HTML5 and CSS3. As far as JavaScript goes, i have used it for form validation, not much else. I have been introduced to the idea of AJAX and JSON. I have used PHP for server-side form validation and formatting and sending contact form information, but not much else. I have almost no experience with MySQL.

I guess i'm looking for people to tell me what i need to know! Are there recurring actions that come up when developing an application? If so, i want to practice these. For instance, is setting up some kind of user information database a common action in application development? I don't know how to this but if it is common i want to know how.

I don't know if i'm making myself clear, but i'm looking for the real basics here. "Often when developing an application, people will need to do x, y, z so that they can do a, b and c".

I'd really appreciate any help with this, as vague and simple as it may seem.

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, iTunes U might be your friend. There are some great courses from Stanford on there for example which essentially take you through the whole thing. The do kind of assume a littl eobject orientated coding experience, but they may be worth dipping in to (and they're free)

Comment: In addition to iTunes U, available from within iTunes, I'd recommend that you download and play with the sample code available from developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Learn Objective-C and iOS Sdk first...
Then you will yourself know what else to learn..

Without these.. learning anything else for iOS specifically is taking the long route for iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right!  Your question is very generic.  If you want to get a start, try this [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).  It has very much all tutorials to get you started...

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with the *UIKit* classes - those will be building blocks of your applications, and you will spend much time customizing them - experiment with different UIViewControllers (navigation, tabbar, table). Learn to use Interface Builder - it will save you lots of time.

A good place to start would be to look at the iOS application templates available in XCode. Create projects with them and see what they use, what you can do with them.

After that... well that depends on what you will be coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a good handle on object oriented design and OO concepts to code iOS apps well. Read about the Model-View-Controller design pattern (MVC) as it proliferates throughout the UIKit libraries.  Understanding OO will help when you start learning objective C.

Understanding MVC will help when you start wiring up nibs to your view-controllers, tying user actions to messages on underlying objects, rendering model data into your views etc.  It will also help in understanding the delegation patterns inherent in most of the UIKit controls.

Getting a basic understanding of how asynchronous processing/threading works is also important and will help in utilising tools like notifications, asynchronous communication (asynch http calls to json/web services etc.). as well as timers, animation etc.